# Export/Import Shp file records to sqlite table

Tags: python, arcpy, shapefile, sqlite

I am new to python and ArcPy. I need to transfer all the records of a single shapefile to a table created in sqlite3 without the geometry.

So far I was only able to retrieve the records using *SearchCursor*. Somehow, I am not able to create a relation between the shp file and sqlite tabe so that I can transfer the data directly. I tried using InsertCursor, but of no use. I am basically confused on approaches to transfer the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only want to load attribute values into a sqlite table, without any spatial information, i believe you could do something like:

```
import arcpy
import sqlite3

# get a list of all column names (or specify them yourself)
columnNames = []
fields = arcpy.ListFields(yourLayer)
for field in fields:
    columnNames.append(field.name)

data = []
# this is approximate - i don't write in arcpy much anymore... so you may have to modify this...
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(yourLayer, columnNames) as sCursor:
    for row in sCursor:
        data.append(row)

# create a connection to your sqlite database (it should make one if it doesn't exist)
conn = sqlite3.connect(pathtoyoursqlitedatabase)
cursor = conn.cursor()

# create a table within the database
sql = 'CREATE TABLE {} ({})'.format('mynewtablename', columnNames)
cursor.execute(sql)

# insert your new records
c = ['?' for c in range(len(columnNames))]
c = ','.join(c)
sql = 'INSERT INTO {} VALUES ({})'.format('mynewtablename', c)
cursor.executemany(sql, data)
conn.commit()
```